# Change from MOV instructions to ADD or SUB instructions

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code, self-modifying

I want to change from mov instructions to SUB instructions (I think ,we can also change to ADD instructions) and I want to adjust the values so that the function of the entire program remains unchanged.

```
   for_real_programmers:
     mov dx, 0 ; 
     inc dx ;

   for_leet_hackorz:
     mov word ptr [for_real_programmers], 0d929h ; ?
     mov word ptr [for_real_programmers+2], 0d9f7h ; ?
     mov byte ptr [for_leet_hackorz], 0c3h ; ?
     jmp restart
```

Comment: Would you please rephrase your question? Do you want to convert `mov` to equivalent `add` or `sub` instructions?

Comment: don't post texts as image. Just copy and paste them here

Comment: Do not post pictures of code.  I have for this reason downvoted your question and will take back my downvote once you [edit] your question and replace the picture with text.

Comment: @fuz ,I think the post is more better more  :) .Thank you for your advice

Comment: You can set a variable to zero by subtracting it from itself. You can increase a variable by 1 by subtracting -1 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The machine-code byte you want to modify are going to be the same every time for this self-modifying code (assuming it only runs once), so yes it is possible to just `add dst, desired - orig_dst` instead of `mov dst, desired`.

First change the `mov` mnemonics to `add` or `sub`, then assemble and look at a listing or hexdump.  That gives you the starting values of the destinations, so you can work out what immediates to use.

Make those changes in your asm source and rebuild again + test.

The bytes you're self-modifying are separate from the immediate operands to mov / add / sub.  One of the bytes you change is replacing the opcode of the first instruction in `for_leet_hackorz` (really?) with a `C3  ret`, which is why you need to change the mnemonics to add or sub *before* calculating the difference between starting vs. desired.

Comment: OK, but when you say :add dst, desired - orig_dst instead of mov dst, desired.,do you mean what exactly ? I know add cx,2ah and I work with assembler 8086 and not with asm @peter Cordes

Comment: I mean a memory-destination `add`, instead of a memory-destination `mov`.  Literally change just the `mov` to `add` in the source.  So the destination is the same as it was for `mov`, but instead of replacing it without caring about the old value of those bytes, you're adding or subtracting to/from it.

Comment: @RoméoTia: "asm" is an abbreviation for "assembly language".  I'm not talking about any specific tool.  That would be like saying "I went to an automated teller machine to get cash, not an ATM".

Comment: Thank you for your reaction .Where I have to put c3 ret exactly? I put it like you notifice ,but it don´t work .I put it on teh first line of For_leet_hackorz .Thank you